# Updating relay store for queries with multiple definitions

Tags: reactjs, offline, relayjs

Normally creating `Relay query` object for queries with single definition can be done using:

```
const relayQuery = Relay.QL `
  query UserRoute($id_0: ID!) {
    user(id:$id_0) {
      id,
      name,
      email
    }
  }
;
```

I have query string intercepted from the one that are sent over network. They normally have multiple definitions (eg. query, fragment, mutation, subscription). I want to create a `Relay query object` for that type of query. The following code throws error:

`Relay transform error "You supplied a GraphQL document named 'network' with 2 definitions, but it must have exactly one definition." in file '/Users/ankitshah/lyearnapp/src/network.js'. Try updating your GraphQL schema if an argument/field/type was recently added.`

for this code:

```
const relayQuery = Relay.QL `
  query UserRoute($id_0: ID!) {
    user(id:$id_0) {
      id,
      ...F0
    }
  }
  fragment F0 on User {
    id,
    name,
    email
  }
;
```

I want this because I want to update Relay Store using `Relay.Store.getStoreData().updateQueryPayload(queryObject, payload)` function. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is your problem solved.,

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same error. You will need to compact your query to  be without fragments like so:

```
const relayQuery = Relay.QL `
  query UserRoute($id_0: ID!) {
    user(id:$id_0) {
      id,
      name,
      email
    }
  }
;
```

Then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using namedspaces . Eg

```
user1 :user(id:$id_0) {
  id,
  name,
  email
```

}

```
user2 :user(id:$id_1) {
  id,
  name,
  email
```

}